# iOS custom-view dynamically resize issue

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiview, subclassing

Basically this is what i have done

I subclassed uiview and created a custom multiple choice view

in the view I resize the frame to fit the content on the fly by doing this

```
    my_frame.size.height = y;
    [self setFrame:my_frame];
```

I want to initiate my custom view in a scrollview and after I init I wanna add more content below.

```
        NSArray *choices = @[@"1", @"2", @"3 ", @"4", @"5", @"6" , @"7"];
        MultipleChoice *mc = [[MultipleChoice alloc]initWithNSArray:choices withFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2 - 125, originY, 0, 0)];
        [_scroll addSubview:mc];
        originY += mc.frame.size.height + 10;
```

The problem that i am having is that when i try to access the height of the frame the resulting value hasn't changed and is 0 so when i use `originY` to create a new label, for example, the label is on top of the multiple choice view

How do I properly obtain the height of the customview during runtime?

Comment: You set the frame CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2 - 125, originY, 0, 0) so here width and height both are set to 0.

Comment: @PradhyumanChavda in my custom view I increase the size of the frame by doing     my_frame.size.height = y;
    [self setFrame:my_frame]; where y is incremented dynamically. So at the end of it the view no longer has a height of 0 same with width

Comment: Where do you change the frame of your `mc`? I mean, in what method of `MultipleChoice`?

Comment: We need context. Where exactly are you executing this code?

Comment: inside of - (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];